# Can I use the next value in advance in v-for?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

[vue playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNp9kstqwzAQRX9l0MYJzYOSXUgKTUmhhbah7S7KwjhjV6ktCUlODUb/3pGcRwMlK1v3npm5I9Sye61H+xrZlM1sZoR2YNHV+o5LUWllHLRgMAcPuVEVJIQmXHKZKWkd6NSgdC9obVogzAPZS1ZRTPpHSDis7MFct1B19BSSR6US8AOacNYWqSFtQ8WzcZeHktCBeugydRhOblYK2A9zZeac9UL7AQi5xaZPn24cZxHkrm07YR2Bm9vN6DALvOcSIBKXa3gPQwh1oeJ8oi4XtRRjXAoaMxufwrEBc5a2zkUx2lkl6VbbOIVlqtKiRPOmnaBb4WwK0QleWpbq5zlqztQ4OOrZF2bf/+g72wSNs5VBi2aPnJ08l5oCXWcvP16xof+TWaltXRJ9xXxHq8o6ZOywRS23FPsPF9M+xbchZPFpl41DaY9LhaCB9JHnjN7Lw5XVz3Eno0ms49Iz/wvLe9/A)

I want to compare the current value and the next value together in v-for

But if you do that, you will end up with an error.

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const parentMessage = ref('Parent')
const items = ref([{ message: 'Foo' }, { message: 'Bar' }])
</script>

<template>
    <li v-for="(item, index) in items">
        {{ items[index+1].message }}
    {{ parentMessage }} - {{ index }} - {{ item.message }}
    </li>
</template>
```

Although you can get the next object with items[index+1]
Getting the items of the items[index+1].message object is giving an error.

Comment: the error stems from the last loop where index+1 has gone beyond the length of the array and is not a valid index.

Comment: Please post the code as a text, not an image.

Answer (score 1):

{{ items[index+1].message }}

When you reach the last item in the loop, an error occurs because you are looking for an undefined object.

Just check whether it is the last object or not.

{{ items[index+1] ? items[index+1].message : '' }}

Answer (score 0):

[Vue SFC Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNp9Us1qAjEQfpUhl1WqK8WbaKEWCy20lbY342FZRxubTUKStcKSd+8k60+F4imZ72fmm5CG3RuT72pkIzZ2pRXGg0NfmzuuRGW09dCAxTUEWFtdQUbSjCuuSq2cB1NYVP4FnSs2CJOo7GTzBGbdo0h4rNyBXDRQteoRZI9aZxB6NOGMTQtL2JLM40Gbh5JQQT2MLDzGyo+lgF1/re2Es05s3wOhVrjv0tGOy50UJXb6t13OkoX7pmmpRZLe3C7zw1QIgSuApLhcKAToQ/RFx7miLhdeCjSQgsaMB6eYrMe8o/3XYpNvnVb0vk2awkpdGSHRvhkv6H04G0FiIldIqX+eE+Ztjb0jXn5h+f0PvnX7iHE2t+jQ7pCzE+cLu0Hf0rOPV9zT/URWelVLUl8h39FpWceMrWxaqxXF/qNLaZ/SLxFq8+lme4/KHZeKQaMyJD1n9HMerqx+jjvMh8nHVWDhF+jJ4q0=)

Since there's no next item for the last item, you could skip the last item with `Array::slice()`:

```
<li v-for="(item, index) in items.slice(-1)">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<li v-for="(item, index) in items">
    {{ items?.[index+1].message }}
{{ parentMessage }} - {{ index }} - {{ item.message }}
</li>
```

You can use `items?.[index+1].message` to make page not crash when `index + 1` is not defined.